# How to convert raster image to vector using only vertical and horizontal segments

Tags: vector, raster, pixel-art, grayscale, tracing

I'm trying to convert an image to a pixel art vector. I want the output to be Only with horizontal and vertical segments "―" "|" (no "╱"). I tried to use several online tools and the best solution for the moment is [potrace](https://potrace.sf.net/).

Here is my progress :
[image]

Does someone know how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Clean up the raster first via threshold, levels, or curve adjustments to eliminate as much of the anti-aliasing "grays" as possible. I don't think an autotrace tool exists that will adhere to *only* perpendicular paths - I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but the PNG image you have is no good. The image appears to have been resampled but this has introduced different coloured pixel squares and blurring (or anti-aliasing) which will cause problems when tracing.

1. Make sure your bitmap image is at 1:1 size to begin with, like this

[image]

2. Rescale the raster image much larger in software such as Photoshop or GIMP.  In Photoshop scale the image using "Nearest neighbour" or in GIMP using "Interpolation: none". In the example below I resampled this to 500 pixels wide. You may also be able to do this in ImageMagick (although I am no expert and don't know the command).
3. This will result in a large clean version of the original, with no blurry pixels
4. Trace the larger version

I don't use Potrace directly, but use Inkscape (which is free) which utilizes Potrace to trace bitmaps.  Here's the result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response . Now i'm looking for a way to achieve this programmatically

Comment: @MattèoGauthier Inkscape can be scripted, so you might want to look into that.  However, I've no idea how to do it. I'm not a programmer. Sorry.  Perhaps ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert it to a bitmap first. This will give you a sharp image in only black and white. You might have to play around with the resolution to match the same pixelation as on the original picture. Then you can autotrace it to a vector.

Comment: I think it misses the point of the question in that it wants "Only with horizontal and vertical segments". If one followed this answer, the trace would provide abstract shapes instead of a bunch of solely horizontal or vertical pieces

Comment: Look at Billy's more detailed answer. Just needs to be 1:1 and then you get the same pixelation.